# What is the Maximum file size for using multipart upload in s3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

Any one have idea on What is the Maximum file size for using multipart upload in 
s3?

because when i tried to upload 10 gb file its got stuck. There is no error message in the log.

can any one have a idea

Thanks in advance

Comment: Documentation states: "Upload objects in parts—Using the multipart upload API, you can upload large objects, up to 5 TB".

Answer (score 3):

The maximum size of an object you can store in an S3 bucket is 5TB so the maximum size of the file using multipart upload also would be 5TB.

Using the multipart upload API, you can upload large objects, up to 5 TB.

The multipart upload API is designed to improve the upload experience for larger objects. You can upload objects in parts. These object parts can be uploaded independently, in any order, and in parallel. You can use a multipart upload for objects from 5 MB to 5 TB in size.

Official documentation- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadingObjects.html

Comment: I thing  thats for S3 bucket. by using multi part upload ?

Comment: S3 bucket you can store unlimited size but each individual file size should be the maximum of 5TB.

Comment: I saw the aws site https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-multipart-upload/. its mentioned "you can break a 5 GB upload (the current limit on the size of an S3 object) into as many as 1024 separate parts and upload each one independently, as long as each part has a size of 5 megabytes (MB) or more. "

Comment: That is old documentation on 2010 and 5GB was the maximum size of a file that time. Now the individual file size is up to 5TB. So you can do multipart upload for a file from 5MB to 5TB.

Comment: @VijayanathViswanathan for clarity, you may wish to add that the largest object you can upload *without* using the multipart API is still 5GB.

Comment: Also, the maximum number of parts for a single upload is 10,000, so for files larger than 50GB you must use a part size not smaller than `CEIL(object_size_bytes / 10000)` bytes, which will be larger than the 5MB minimum part size for multipart uploads.

Comment: There is a page dedicated to the multipart upload limits https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/qfacts.html. The last is allowed to be less than 5MB so I think it may support files smaller than this provided it is a single part. In saying that multipart upload is most useful when your file is over 100MB.